# CanvasJS and PHP

Tags: javascript, php, charts, canvasjs

I want to create two charts with CanvasJS in which I use values from php file.
I have two charts but only one renders, the second one has only white background and title text.
Here's php code with values:

```
 <?php
require 'excCon.php';
$dataPoints = array(
    array("y" => $excel_result, "label" => "Quantity"),
    array("y" => $excel_result2, "label" => "Value"),
    );

$dataP = array(
    array("y" => $excel_result3, "name" => "1", "exploded" => false),
    array("y" => $excel_result4, "name" => "2"),
    array("y" => $excel_result5, "name" => "3&5"),
    array("y" => $excel_result6, "name" => "4"),
    );
?>
```

and javascript:

```
<div id="chartContainer style="height: 400px;width: 80%"">
                <script type="text/javascript">
                    $(function () {
                        var chart1 = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer", {
                            theme: "theme2",
                            animationEnabled: true,
                            title: {
                                text: "Sum"
                            },
                            data: [
                                {
                                    type: "column",
                                    dataPoints: <?php echo json_encode($dataPoints, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK); ?>
                                }
                        ]
                        });
                        chart1.render();
                    });
                </script>
            </div>
            <div id="chartContainer2" style="height: 400px;width: 80%">
                <script type="text/javascript">
                    $(function () {
                        var chart2 = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer2",
                            {
                                theme: "theme2",
                                title:{
                                    text: "All"
                                },
                                exportFileName: "All",
                                exportEnabled: false,
                                animationEnabled: false,
                                data: [
                                    {
                                        type: "pie",
                                        showInLegend: true,
                                        toolTipContent: "{name}: <strong>{y}%</strong>",
                                        indexLabel: "{name} {y}%",
                                        dataP: <?php echo json_encode($dataP, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK); ?>
                                    }]
                            });
                        chart2.render();
                    });
                </script>
            </div>
```

The whole code is in `index.php` file.

For the record, I searched other solutions here as well as on the official page and none worked.

Comment: I think that the problem is with `dataPoints`. It has to be `dataPoints` in every chart but how do I do that without having everytime the same values?

Answer (score 0):

Solution is to have dataPoints in data and do not change it

```
data: [
{
type: "column",
**dataPoints** : <?php echo json_encode($dataP, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK); ?>
```